# backbone.js and scoped urls

Tags: backbone.js, router

Currently I keep the current locale and account id only in global variables. But now I need to embed them in the url's of my backbone application, so the users can copy/ paste the url.

Currently:

```
/#users
/#documents
/#images
...
```

Desired:

```
/#de/32/users
/#de/232/documents
/#de/4452/images
...
```

I wonder what's the best way to extract and store the current locale and account id from the url before any router processes it. This way I should be able to leave all routers as they are, am I?

Do I have to "hack" this into the routers (something like in https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/pull/299) or is there any better way?

Answer (score 1):

I really wouldn't play with internal Backbone mechanism, especially when you can move your code to accomplish the Backbone standards.

I rather recommend to modify all your urls to accept the two new values:

```
:locale/:account_id/users
:locale/:account_id/documents
:locale/:account_id/images
...
```

Also, you want *to extract and store these values* with a handmade mechanism and this is exactly one of the meanings of Router, if you are not careful you can ended up *reinventing the wheel*.